# Can a python3 implementation of virtualenv safely create python2 environments (and vice versa)?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, python-2.x

Can the virtualenv command installed by `pip3 install virtualenv` be used to safely create python2 environments (E.G. `python3 -m virtualenv -p "$(which python2)" venv2` and vice versa?

Comment: I know that  `venv` is new for python3, but the issue that has been raised is what happens if the end user has ended up in this situation (we're using python2 here until the libraries we need get ported).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use that all the time. I have one version of `virtualenv` and create virtual environments for many Python versions from 2.7 to 3.6 and also for PyPy.